# Docker production ready php-fpm and nginx configuration

Tags: php, nginx, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a small theoretical problem with combination of php-fpm, nginx and app code in Docker.

I'm trying to stick to the model when docker image does only one thing -> I have separate containers for php-fpm and nginx.

```
php:
    image: php:5-fpm-alpine
    expose:
        - 9000:9000
    volumes:
        - ./:/var/www/app

nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
        - 3000:80
    links:
        - php
    volumes:
        - ./nginx/app.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf
        - ./:/var/www/app
```

*NOTE:* In app.conf is `root /var/www/app;`
[Example schema from Symfony](https://vincent.composieux.fr/assets/img/blog/containers-schema.jpg)

This is great in development, but I don't know how to convert this to production ready state. Mount app directory in production is really bad practice (if I'm not wrong). In best case I copy app source code into container and use this prebuilded code (`COPY . /var/www/app` in `Dockerfile`), but in this case is impossible or I don't know how.

I need share app source code between two contatiner (nginx container and php-fpm container) because booth of that need it.

Of course I can make own nginx and php-fpm container and add `COPY . /var/www/app` into both of them, but I thing that is wrong way because I duplicate code and the whole build process (install dependencies, build source code, etc...) must be in both (nginx/php-fpm) containers.

I try to search but I don't find any idea how to solve this problem. A lot of articles show how to do this with docker-compose file and mount code with --volume but I didn't find any example how to use this on production (without volume).

Only one acceptable solutions for me (in this time) is make one container with nginx and php-fpm together but I'm not sure when is a good way (**I try to find *best practice***).

Do you have any experiences with this or any idea how to solve it?

Thanks for any response!

Comment: same problem :( i need help too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this time I use smth like:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:fpm
COPY . /var/www/app/
WORKDIR /var/www/app/
RUN composer install
EXPOSE 9000
VOLUME /var/www/app/web
```

Dockerfile.nginx

```
FROM nginx
COPY default /etc/nginx/default
```

docker-compose.yml

```
app:
  build:
    context: .
web:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile.nginx
  volumes_from: app
```

But in few days on 17.05 release we can do in one Dockerfile smth like:

```
FROM php:cli AS builder
COPY . /var/www/app/
WORKDIR /var/www/app/
RUN composer install && bin/console assets:dump

FROM php:fpm AS app
COPY --from=builder /var/www/app/src /var/www/app/vendor /var/www/app/
COPY --from=builder /var/www/app/web/app.php /var/www/app/vendo /var/www/app/web/

FROM nginx AS web
COPY default /etc/nginx/default
COPY --from=builder /var/www/app/web /var/www/app/web
```

Comment: Using multistage build in this way will not solve the problem. If you run this dockerfile, only one image is created (the one with the latest FROM instruction).

Comment: @JimPanse there are `docker build --target` option & `target` key in `build` section of docker.compose

Comment: Thats right! I found that option yesterday ... with this option, building images is amazing!

Answer (score 6):

I solve the problem by making a shared volume with the docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

volumes:
 share_place:

services:
 php:
  image: php:5-fpm-alpine
  ports:
   - 9000:9000
  volumes:
   - share_place:/var/www/app
 nginx:
  image: nginx:alpine
  ports:
   - 3000:80
  volumes:
   - share_place:/var/www/app
```

This will create a volume share_place that will share the data between the two container.